# Why Random Access Memory, RAM, called "Random Access"?

Tags: terminology

[Mark Hahn,](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-RAM-called-random-access-memory)

> RAM is not random-access. It’s much more like disk, which has two-dimensional access, and an inherent block-size.

[Vikki Kinsella](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-RAM-called-random-access-memory)

> So in order to give you the correct answer, I'm going to copy part of a paragraph from Wikipedia's article on Random Access Memory:
>
> “The first practical form of random-access memory was the [Williams tube](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_tube)
>
> starting in 1947. It stored data as electrically charged spots on the face of a [cathode ray tube](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube)
>
> . Since the electron beam of the CRT could read and write the spots on the tube in any order, memory was random access. “
>
> It's the last sentence that truly answers the question at hand - “read and write … in any order”, not just be forced to select an area of the matrix and read the whole of that in one block (shift registers). Or, worse still, have to start at the beginning of the storage medium and read its entire contents everytime you want to access a single bit of data (punched tape).

I agree. I don't see nothing "random" and no "random access". Isn't QUICK Access Memory accurater? "the electron beam of the CRT could read and write the spots on the tube in any order." But "spots on the tube" AREN'T RANDOM. The CRT's electron beam isn't reading and writing RANDOM spots.

[A reader asks: “Why is RAM called random access memory?” – Langa.com](https://langa.com/index.php/2018/12/28/a-reader-asks-why-is-ram-called-random-access-memory/)

> Recall that early computers used tape as memory — paper tape at first and later, magnetic tape. Tape-based memory is ***serial***: If you want a byte of memory in the middle of the tape, you have to start at one end of the tape and spool through to the location you want. That’s clumsy and slow.
>
> In early PCs, which used cassette audio tapes for memory, it was not uncommon for ***tens of seconds*** to pass before the PC could even begin to retrieve a particular piece of information from a tape. You’d sit there twiddling your thumbs while the tape drive whined its way to the location you needed.
>
> RAM lets you access any memory address directly, in one step, without having to pass through any other addresses first. That means you can access memory locations in any order — not just by slogging through in 1-2-3 serial fashion.
>
> Plus, although this has nothing to do with the random-access part, RAM is electronic, operating at nanosecond speeds instead of the vastly slower speeds of mechanical tape transport. Combined, these two advantages — random access and electronic speed — make RAM ***multiple orders of magnitude*** faster than mechanical, serial memory. There’s no comparison at all!

[ELI5: Why is RAM called Random Access Memory? : explainlikeimfive](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2k1zyg/eli5_why_is_ram_called_random_access_memory/clh61f1/)

> Think of a grid, with an x-axis and a y-axis. Think of the data as bits that can be located at any x-y coordinate. Now, imagine that the processor can place any bit at any x-y coordinate in that grid, and then retrieve it very quickly, since there is no physical media (like a hard drive) that needs to be physically manipulated (spun) in order to be read. The fact that the data can be stored and retrieved from anywhere in the "grid" is where the "random access" comes into play. The computer stores the data wherever there's a place to store it... doesn't matter where.
>
> The data only exists in RAM so long as power is applied. Turn off the PC, and the data in RAM is lost. This, BTW, is technically the main difference between "memory" like RAM (which is volatile) and "storage" like a hard drive (which is relatively permanent)... people often mistakenly refer to storage as "memory".
>
> I mention this in case you too are laboring under this misunderstanding... no offense is intended, it's just a pet peeve of mine ;)
>
> Before I get flamed, please let me say that I know the term has morphed into being used for both, but that doesn't mean I have to like it! And I also know there is relatively permanent memory, like ROM... but usually I hear people asking about "memory" when they really mean hard drive storage space. So please be nice.
>
> TL;DR RAM is a "grid" where data can be stored essentially as electricity and quickly retrieved.

Comment: I'm sorry, is this actually a question?

Comment: @music2myear Yes!!!!

Comment: The answer is in one of the things you quoted.  "The fact that the data can be stored and retrieved from anywhere in the "grid" is where the "random access" comes into play."

Comment: @kicken that doesn't deal with what i wrote above.

Comment: @DongmeiWang, It's random because it's not sequential.  You can jump between whatever random address locations you want instead of having to move sequentially from one address to the next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Random" refers to the fact that there is no penalty for switching between memory locations. There is effectively no difference between sequential and random reads, unlike other types of media.

RAM may have a similar "2D" array layout as other memory types but it has none of the head movement or area selection drawbacks of "sequential" memory types such as hard disks, tape drives or CD ROMs.

The names for a lot of these computing terms were coined in an era when tape drives were common, and even paper punch cards were used. Neither of those could easily be used in a random fashion. They typically forced you to scan the entire media in one long sequential fashion to find the spot you want. Even now hard disks have to seek to the area, wait for the data to move under the head and *then* start reading.

It has nothing to do with physical layout nor speed of the device. In terms of speed SSDs are coming close to RAM speeds, but they still prefer sequential over random access.

Most storage devices have a natural preference for **sequential** access rather than **random** access. RAM doesn't. RAM allows truly random access at all times.

---

RAM, unlike most storage media, has full and dedicated address **and** data buses connected to the CPU. This address bus means that memory needs very little in the way of active controller and switching between areas is effectively "free". There is a tiny penalty, sure, but it is far less than in other types of device. While I agree with your original link by Mark Hahn on *that* technicality he is largely wrong about the main part of it. Separate buses means that the address can be being changed all the time, with data "simply" flowing in one direction or the other.

Other storage devices do not have *direct* and dedicated address bus access by the CPU. They all have a data channel and need some kind of controller that has to wait for a command, decode that command, seek for data, receive data, and then marshal it out to the CPU. They may have "grab next block" commands that can make things faster, but once they see a new address command they have to essentially start again from scratch. Random access and sequential access have very different performance characteristics due to using a command protocol to access media. They lack the fast dual-bus that gives RAM its "easy" access to any memory location at any moment.

RAM may have some buffering, but it has none of the controller overhead for command decode and switching.