# Why computers still need ram to boot?

Tags: boot, memory, ssd, bios, development

That was reasonable 20 years ago where the fastest storage media was a diskette but now we have ssd's and I bet that even oldest sata drives are faster than the old pc100 ram but we still need ram and not just ram but super fast modern ram to solely turn on the pc.

Surely you would ask who would want to run a modern pc at the speed of a pc100 ram? Well, it's called redundancy and it's usefull for troubleshooting you know? That's also why we (used to) have a bios installed under the actual os. If you could boot the pc using only a pendrive it would be far easier to check defective ram or other component, instead of buying new ram just to know if the mobo is fine you could just insert a pendrive and see iif it boots.

Also in a wide way some computers are yet able to boot without ram and are called intelligent devices, which totally discarded ram in favor of ssd, hence why modern pc's can't do so just in order to be able to access bios or uefi and change some settings? I'm not telling of playing games on this but be able to use it as an alternate path.

Is this lack of implementation because of lack of physical posibilities or because of tradition and lack of development?

Comment: All you need to troubleshoot is for the motherboard to tell you "hey, there's no RAM here, fix it", which a lot of motherboards will do with either beep codes or seven-segment displays. Actually booting something without RAM could probably be done with enough trickery (although with northbridges fully integrated into CPUs these days it would be fairly challenging), but it's of questionable use to pretty much any home user.

Comment: What "intelligent devices" have done away with RAM? I put to you the abstraction layer on SSD is a problem, as is the limited number of writes.  I expect your conjecture about old sata drives being faster then pc100 memory is false. Most 5400 rpm SATA hard drives would perform worse.

Comment: Your post completely ignores how a CPU fetches & executes instructions.  Your question is based on ignorance and/or misinformation.  E.G. the `program counter` is a CPU register that points to the next instruction to fetch & execute.  This `program counter` contains a memory (i.e. RAM) address.  How do propose to redesign the CPU to have  the `program counter` access a SSD which uses LBA?

Comment: In fact, rather than eliminating RAM, modern chips incorporate it into the actual CPU itself, to get access times down even further & allow all components equal access, rather than copying & handing off - unified memory architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Because RAM still has something that even SSDs don't: [true random access](https://superuser.com/questions/1551555/why-random-access-memory-ram-called-random-access/1551594#1551594), and having both address and data buses connected straight to the CPU

SSDs may well be fast, but they still rely on a controller and are accessed over a "Data" bus that transfers both addresses, to tell the drive controller where to read/write, and data telling it *what* to read and write. A PCIe link does not distinguish between "address" and "data" busses and uses a combined bus and a controller at each side to encode and decode addresses and data.

RAM on the other hand is connected directly to the CPU, has no "real" protocol (unlike PCIe which has a packetised "I'm talking to this card at that address" protocol) apart from the hardware access protocol which is entirely built into the CPU.

That direct connection and separate address and data busses means that the RAM is 100% accessible to the CPU with absolutely no extra hardware or software required and makes it completely suited for being the place the CPU uses to store *anything* it needs to do. Need to write something to disk? It goes to RAM first, then gets copied to a controller to write to disk. Want to display something? It goes to RAM first and then gets copied over PCIe using drivers and other hardware controllers to get to the end destination.

Need to copy some data in RAM? The CPU literally knows where it is in RAM and just gets down and dirty and just copies it.

Everything other than RAM *needs* the system, drivers, and other hardware to do work. RAM is so ingrained in the way the system works that it is literally a part of the system substrate.

To do anything in RAM it is the absolute minimum block of "write data at that address" and the CPU just knows it. To copy data over PCIe the CPU needs to know system architecture, what PCIe bus, what device, what driver, what bridge it is behind and is a lot more complicated.

And RAM is *still* the fastest media for a CPU to work with, even 20 years on, and the ever increasing speeds/efficiency of CPU cores means they still need *fast* in order to keep them saturated and working.

Comment: But it could be possible to make an integrated chip that makes that function of emulation in order to make ssd storage accessible as ram to the cpu? It would be a chip that interfaces in middle of cpu and and a sata or usb connector. It shouldn't be so expensive to make, or I am wrong?

Comment: That "integrated chip" would need some kind of protocol, firmware or translation layer (i.e. software) that knows how to communicate with an external device instead of RAM. Why would you bother with that when you can simply give the CPU a minimal amount of RAM and let someone else decide what hardware and software they want to connect to it? Even the smallest ARM M0 cores come with some built in RAM for the core to use as a scratchpad to do the actual work.

Comment: If you screw up that emulation layer or otherwise want to replace it for a slightly different system then you have to bin that silicon and start again from nearly scratch rather than having a generic piece of hardware with added RAM and everything else handled in software that can be changed to match how the rest of the hardware is set up. Sure you can make something that is super specialised and only useable in 0.0001% of use-cases, or you can make something that works for 99.9999% of use cases and can be fixed to work with the rest.

Comment: Can't use both 0.0001% and 99.9999% at the same time? Only add a OR gateway: If no ram then use hardware emulation else use ram. that seems like a 100.000% of cases

Comment: @LerianAcosenossa - DDR modules are already ICs.  Your followup questions are not well researched

Comment: But that costs money and engineering effort. If you have some part of the CPU that is never active then you've wasted time and money. You are coming from the direction of "I want to do this so why can't I?" Rather than ""why do we need to change something that is proven and works perfectly well for almost everyone on the planet for several generations."

Comment: @ler as Ramhound mentions we already have controllers that do allow a CPU to connect to a SATA disk. The problem is that we have approximately 5 billion SATA disks all with different capacities, different bad block lists, different speeds and other features that all can vary over time. RAM is a finite thing, guaranteed to work the same way at the same speed forever until it just gives up and dies or gets replaced. SATA needs some kind of disk controller, possibly even a filesystem, RAM needs nothing more than addresses and data.

Comment: What I think this answer is missing is that CPUs also have onboard cache memory which *can* be used to execute code in the absence of RAM (that's pretty much how coreboot works, for example). You could even [squeeze the entire Linux kernel into L3, apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699197/cache-as-ram-no-fill-mode-executable-code). It's just pretty pointless on consumer systems.